# How to improve my webAPI performance and how to manage CPU usage in image Processing API?

Tags: .net, image-processing, model-view-controller, imagemagick, iis-8

I have created MVC .Net API where I am generating images dynamically through Imagemagick. If I get 500 requests at one time to access images, then my API is starts working very slowly and my CPU usage suddenly goes high to 100%.

Can you please suggest to me how I can manage CPU load and improve my API performance?

My Configuration

1. 8 core CPU
2. 2 TB hard disk
3. 128 GB Ram

Please help me.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Image processing is by design resource exhaustive, so I won't be surprised. You might tune ASP.NET thread pool manually https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/821268/contention-poor-performance-and-deadlocks-when-you-make-calls-to-web-s but the gain should be limited.

Comment: Be sure to set your policy.xml file limits as high as possible and if you want half the memory storage install Q8 version of ImageMagick rather than the default Q16.

Answer (score 0):

Five hundred imagemagick processes running at once will kill almost any server. I would do some experiments to determine typical memory use for a single task, calculate how many will fit comfortably in your 128gb of memory, then cap your threadpool to stay within that.

You could also consider other image processing packages. It depends on the task, but [net-vips](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips) can be [8 times faster than imagemagick](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/tree/master/tests/NetVips.Benchmarks) and need [10 times less memory](https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use).

Comment: So Can I use a Linux machine for processing images? Becasue I am looking for something that I need to processing no of image same time.

Comment: Sure, it runs on anything.